# Display data in tabular manner in PHP form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table

I want to do something like this..

I have a update form in PHP, which contains around 15 fields,

I want to show some data in tabular manner while you open the page for update..

Senario:

If you want to update a record of a person on day to day basis, I have the feature with me to search out that person form database, and when you click on update data..

it should show in a manner that,

field1.....----------
field2.....----------
field3.....----------

and now,

for field4,5,6,7

if these fields contain the data then show in a table manner with fields 4,5,6,7 as coloums and no of rows depending upon the number of entries (should be non editable)(assume the case of multiple input)

then form will continue.
field4.....--------
field5.....--------
field6.....--------
field7.....--------

typically these field(4,5,6,7) gets their value update frequently and I have to maintain the previous inputs also.

help me out with some solution, as I am unable to figure out how to do this?

before that i was using this.. here i was having a form field which can generate 5 options, and will populate the fields with data if u have entered before, now i want to change the display as I don't want user to play with the old data, so I want to show old data into a table and enter new data via a simple text field,

as their is no point to keep these multiple input form field as user is updating only one value at a time.

```
<script>
                    function Submitted_Date(value,object)
                    {
                    value = document.getElementById("subdate_num").value;
                    if (value > -1) {
                    var input= new Array(value);
                    var p;
                    //alert("Enter The fields You Know ");


               var ele = document.getElementById("subdate");

              if(ele.hasChildNodes())
              {
              var len = ele.childNodes.length;
              while(ele.childNodes.length - value > 1)
             {
                ele.removeChild(ele.lastChild);
             }
             }

          for (var i=len-1;i<value;i++)
                    {
                        p= i+1;
                        input[i] = document.createElement('div');

                        input[i].innerHTML = 'Submitted_Date' + p + ':  &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" value="" name="subdate' + p + '" id="subdate' + p +'" size = 25 onclick="javascript: showCalendar("Submitted_Date'+ p +'")"/>';
                                    document.getElementById("subdate").appendChild(input[i]);
                                    var subdate = 'subdate' + p;



                    }
              }
              document.getElementById("subdate1").focus();

                    }
                    </script>


                    <tr>
    <td> Submitted Date  : 
        <select name="subdate_num" id="subdate_num" onChange="return Submitted_Date(this.value,this.form)">
          <?php
  for ($i=0;$i<=5;$i++)
  {
    if ($i==0) { $temp = "<option value=$i> - </option>"; echo $temp; }
    else { $temp = "<option value=$i>$i</option>";
    echo $temp; }
  }
  ?>
        </select></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

```
<table>
```

Comment: @KingFisher : post edited and added details, check and help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, this will show the information in a table with as many (or few) columns as you want

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM announcements ORDER BY announceid";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Announcement ID</th>
<th>Announcement Name</th>
<th>Announcement Category</th>
<th>Approved?</th>
<th></th>
</tr>";

if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$x = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['announceid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['category_name'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><a href="edit.php?announceid='.$row['announceid'].'">Edit</a></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
$x ++;
};

  echo "</table>";
```

Let me know if that is what you are looking for, or if there is any other way I can help. Thanks!

Comment: can i make this table editable.
let suppose u want to change the "status" by clicking in the table field itself, and it should get edited by the value which u provide...